# Validate expression in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have this expression:

```
vm.optins_rate_goal ? ((vm.optin/vm.optins_rate_goal)*100) : 0
```

I need validate this piece of said expression :

```
((vm.optin/vm.optins_rate_goal)*100)
```

When that result is higher than 100, I need to show just 100. How can I do this?

Comment: How about `Math.min(((vm.optin / vm.optins_rate_goal) * 100), 100)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(vm.optin > vm.optins_rate_goal ? 1 : vm.optin / vm.optins_rate_goal) * 100`

Answer (score 0):

Use a function for it. Code should be readable, not crammed into one line at any cost.

```
calculateSomething(obj) {
  const result = (obj.optin / obj.optins_rate_goal) * 100;
  return result > 100 ? 100 : result;
}

vm.optins_rate_goal ? (calculateSomething(vm)) : 0
```

BTW, it's javascript question, not angular.
BTW2, angularjs and angular are completely different frameworks, please don't use both tags at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate function for this.

```
getOptinsRateGoal(vm) {
  if (vm.optins_rate_goal) {
    var result = (vm.optin / vm.optins_rate_goal) * 100;
    return (result > 100) ? 100 : result;
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

And then just call it in the template.

The other way is to add one more ternary operand but that means you have to calculate the `(vm.optin / vm.optins_rate_goal) * 100` expression twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and a [Pipe](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe) in Angular or a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in AngularJS 1.x.

Basic js expression:

```
Math.min((vm.optin/vm.optins_rate_goal)*100, 100);
```

Reusable Angular Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'max'
})
export class MaxPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, max: number): string {
    return Math.min(value, max);
  }
}
```

Reusable AngularJS 1.x filter:

```
app.filter('max', () => { 
  return (value, max) => {
    return Math.min(value,max);
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
{{ ((vm.optin/vm.optins_rate_goal)*100) | max:100 }}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, using a pipe. In this case, would it perhaps be more obvious if it were called `max` to highlight that the pipe would be ensuring a maximum value of e.g. 100?

Comment: @KirkLarkin It probably would, I'll change that  :)